# MX Select Plus CE - problems with SQL Query

Tags: query, sql, mx-select-plus

I've added **MX Select Plus CE** in a Matrix row. The objective is when the user is digitizing inside the select options, appears "on the fly" the "title" of theses entries of a specific channel.

I chose a SQL query:

```
SELECT title FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE channel_id = '2'
```

Inside these **{exp:query}** fields, appears all the titles of the entries.

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT title FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE channel_id = '2'"}
          {title}
{/exp:query}
```

So inside the **MX Select Plus CE** - **DB REQUEST field**, I inserted the SQL Query:

```
SELECT title FROM exp_channel_titles WHERE channel_id = '2'
```

But in the Channel Entries Edit page, appears error messages:

```
Message: Undefined index: option_name 
Message: Undefined index: option_label
```

Inside the DB REQUEST field, what are the parameters for **option_name** and **option_label**. Does my SQL Query is correct ?

Does someone have a simple example about to show the titles of channel or other parameters and the option_name and option_label parameters?

Comment: I'll give this a crack however can you tell us if the field works ok in the Admin CP? (i.e. can you set your channel title from the drop down when you create/edit an entry?), Are you trying to replicate this for users to enter entried via the Channel Entries form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the example on the Field display :

> ex 1: SELECT action_id as option_name, method as option_label, class as optgroup FROM exp_actions ORDER BY class

You will see that the query needs to mark the fields option_label and option_value within the query, using the `AS` operator.

Ergo, to replicate your query I have assumed you wish to display the Entry Title, and store the Entry ID, therefor I used :

```
SELECT entry_id AS option_name, title AS option_label 
FROM exp_channel_titles 
WHERE channel_id = '2'
```

I set this up and the field worked fine on the edit/publish CP pages, however it caused another error on Save.

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: is_array() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given
Filename: mx_select_plus/ft.mx_select_plus.php
Line Number: 608
```

So I inspected this line, sure enought there seems to be a type-o here (Line 698 of `ft.mx_select_plus.php`:

```
$data = ( is_array() ) ? implode( '|', $data ) : $data;
```

That doesn't look right! I changed this to :

```
$data = ( is_array($data) ) ? implode( '|', $data ) : $data;
```

This makes the `is_array` call valid and my entry is duely saved.

I can display my selected entry too, however this too is also bugged (i'd get the ticket ready for http://www.eec.ms as the documentation if not good either!), it will only display the saved value, not the label when using a database query. Fixing this is way beyond scope however this should get you started.

In summary, I'm seeing some issues in MX Select Plus specifically when using a DB query, I don't think its the 100% finished article. Hopefully the guys over at EEC.MS (MaxLazar, where are you?? :D) will see this and have a look for you.

Otherwise you could report the `is_array` issue and the lack of loading/saving values/labels when using a db query here : https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-select-plus/issues

Comment: Hi Blatant. Thanks a lot for your very useful answer. I tried your SQL Query and it's working fine (the EE doc about query is very light). Thanks too to solve the PHP error problems.

Comment: Very happy to help :) however you should poke the guys that build it (assuming Max doesn't see this) as it does seem to be holding some errors in this 3rd party fieldtype!

Comment: I will write to to Max about this. Before, MX Select was a commercial add-on, that i bought.

Comment: Blatant. Thanks for this post. Very Helpful.